# How to request reopen/undelete a question deleted by community?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, moderators, vote-to-undelete

I have a question that has been deleted by community moderator. I had improved the question by adding more details.

I requested by raising a flag but it was declined. So shall I ask a new question or is there a method to undelete that?

P.S: It was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159399/where-are-gzipped-files-saved-by-gulp-in-webapp-generated-project) question. Although I am asking in general. This is the flag status:

> I had added more info. If its not enough then plz mention what else I need to explain. – user31782 yesterday   declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

May be I didn't explicitly ask for undeletion?

Comment: I suspect not explicitly asking for undeletion was the problem. It's possible that just asking here on meta will result in undeletion as high rep users can vote to undelete just like mods.

Comment: @RobertLongson So in principle, if any of my questions gets deleted by automatic script(community bot) then I should improve the question more and raise a flag asking explicitly for undeletion?

Comment: Just to note that the community bot auto-deletions don't require a mod to undelete even though it looks like it should because of the diamond after its name.

Comment: AFAIK, your first edit to a closed question will put it into a Reopen queue, available to those members who have over 3k reputation. If they feel so, they'll cast reopen votes (I think it requires 2 or 3). Failing that, if the members decide to leave it closed, I'm not sure what you can do. Asking on meta with a link to the question means only people with over 10k rep can see and action it.

Comment: @Tas As far as I remember the question never got closed. Even if it were then it would have been reopened and I had already edited it many days before it was deleted. I don't know what other details are required after the deletion. That's why I asked in flag what improvements are needed.

Comment: @tas: 5 reopen votes. You may be thinking of the three Leave Open reviews necessary to kick a question out of the CV queue before it's closed, but those aren't recorded anywhere other than the queue itself, and are reset if the question reenters the queue for any reason.

Comment: @NathanTuggy completed reviews will appear on the post's timeline.

Comment: @JonClements: Yeah, sorry, that wasn't quite clear; I meant they're not recorded *in any context* but the review itself, and don't e.g. carry over as reopen votes, Leave Open votes in other reviews, etc. Obviously yes they are available to see in the history if that particular review is opened.

Comment: @Tas I think that only applies in the first ~6 days after closure, after that editing it won't put the question in the reopen queue. (And this only happens once, which is a very good reason why facelift edits to newly closed low-quality questions should be rejected)